# How to set Transparent TEdit AlphaBlendValue in TEdit

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6, alphablending

I want to make transparent `TEdit`
I would use the function `AlphaBlendValue` but I can not, does anyone have any solution ?, any component that has `TEdit` with `AlphaBlendValue`?

Example:

```
Edit1.AlphaBlend := True;
Edit1.AlphaBlendValue := 0;
```

Comment: If you're really going to use '0', you can set the visible property to false instead.

Comment: What do you mean by transparent? Which part is transparent?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Example: http://puu.sh/cK9qA/db9367e9ac.png to http://puu.sh/cK9sV/28d0694670.png Bottomless, borderless.

Comment: You're not looking for alpha blending, that would make the text transparent too.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787609(v=vs.85).aspx